# Unable to connect to server after a certain amount of time

Tags: networking

I am a business FIOS subscriber with 5 static IPs. I have the following network setup:

Verizon provided ONT > Dlink switch > Dell server running Ubuntu 12.04 with iptables enabled and a static IP address.

The makes/models of hardware are:

FIOS ONT
Alcatel-Lucent I-211M-H ONT

D-Link
D-Link Web Smart Switch DES-1228P

Server
Dell Optiplex 755 (Ubuntu 12.04 Server)

I have iptables running on the server with http, https and ssh ports open. I can connect to a website on the server from an external computer, but after a certain amount of time (mins to hours), I can no longer connect. All I have to do to re-enable connectivity is connect to the server via SSH from a computer INSIDE the network. I don't have to actually login, I just have to establish a connection. I can then access the website externally again.

I did some googling and it seems some of verizon's equipment had an ARP bug where the ARP entries would expire after a certain time period, but those issues all seem to be from back in 2009 - 2010. I know the switch has an 'auto learning Mac address' feature, but I'm not sure if that could be the problem or not. Does anyone have any ideas or advice on how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to setup a cron job on the server that pings Google (or something else) once a minute and see if this solves the problem. If yes, you are right with the ARP table issue and should request  a replacement from the provider.

Comment: Would the issue be with the ONT or the switch?

Comment: I installed the cron job like you suggested and I've been able to connect now for about 9-hours. It seems to have resolved the issue for now. I'm not sure if the fault lies with the switch or the ONT but I'll try contacting Verizon. Haven't had much success w/ them though...8-)

Comment: Got a hold of Verizon and they said they did the following to the ONT:

1) Turned the Mac filtering up to ten
2) Fixed the ARP settings...

Sure enough, problem solved. No downtime for the last 12-hours or so anyway.

Thanks for your help!